# Spring web Application on AWS EBS not working with my Angular front End

Tags: angular, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deploy my spring boot application on AWS EBS; when I try to signin with my front end app I have a connection timeout error and no cross origin error.

In local and with postman it's working well.
I need your helps !!!.

Here is a part of my code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/myschool")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*" ,maxAge = 3600, methods ={OPTIONS, DELETE, GET, POST, PUT}, allowCredentials = "true", exposedHeaders = "Authorization")
public class AccountResource {

  ...
}
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
// @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
  //  prePostEnabled = true
//)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        ...
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
         http.cors();
         ...
```

Comment: Are you using a loadbalancer, if so what do the logs say? If not; is your application listening on the correct port?

Comment: I am not using the loadbalancer. My application is lisntenning on port 5000.